# Render React component in Django template view and replace original tag with component content

Tags: reactjs, django, rendering, dom-manipulation

We have a Django template that includes a custom HTML tag, . We want to replace this tag with a React component, HelloWorld, while keeping the final DOM structure as clean as possible. However, the current implementation results in an extra div element wrapping the component content, and we are unable to remove it.

**Django template:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>My Website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <HelloWorld name="Alice" />
  </body>
</html>
```

**React component:**

```
import React from 'react';

function HelloWorld(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, {props.name}!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HelloWorld;
```

**Current implementation:**
We are using the following code to render the HelloWorld component and replace the original  tag in the Django template:

```
function initReactApp() {
  const components = {
    HelloWorld,
  };

  for (const componentName of Object.keys(components)) {
    // find components by their HTML tag name
    const componentElements = document.getElementsByTagName(componentName);
    for (let element of componentElements) {
      // assign the actual component function of the componentName
      const Component = components[componentName];
      // collect all properties of the element to pass them to the dynamic component
      const props = Object.fromEntries(
        [...element.attributes].map(({ name, value }) => [name, value])
      );

      // render the dynamic component and mount it in the DOM
      const domNode = document.createElement("div");
      let componentRoot = createRoot(domNode);
      componentRoot.render(<Component {...props} />);
      element.replaceWith(domNode);
    }
  }
}

export default initReactApp;
```

The code above correctly renders the HelloWorld component and passes the name prop to it, but it also includes an extra div element that wraps the component content. We have tried using `createRoot(element).render(<Component {...props} />)` instead of `createRoot(domNode).render(<Component {...props} />)` to render the component directly inside the original tag, but this still results in the extra div element. Additionally, using `element.replaceWith(element.children)` does not work because the children are not available until the render process is finished, at which point the extra div element is already present.

Any suggestions for removing the extra div element would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit:**
It seems to work with React version 17 this way

```
// render the dynamic component and mount it in the DOM
  const portalElement = ReactDOM.createPortal(<Component {...props} />, element);
  ReactDOM.render(portalElement, element);
  element.replaceWith(element.firstChild);
```

But I'm wondering how to implement this with version 18.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution you are searching for is called '[Fragment](https://react.dev/reference/react/Fragment)'

> Fragments are useful because grouping elements with a Fragment has no effect on layout or styles, unlike if you wrapped the elements in another container like a DOM element. If you inspect this example with the browser tools, you’ll see that all  and  DOM nodes appear as siblings without wrappers around them:

Comment: I tried something with `document.createDocumentFragment();`  but it seems that it is not possible to use **createRoot** on a DocumentFragmentElement or any other type of virtual DOM Element. So there is still that additional div element in the DOM